# Visual Studio 2022 not showing Compiler error in "Error List" Tab when the file is closed

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

we recently migrated from Visual Studio 2019 to Visual Studio 2022.
we are seeing this issue of editor not showing compiler error when the files are not open.
They only show up in the Error List in the IDE when the file is opened.
we tried the below options but to no avail.

1. deleted .vs folder and reloaded the project
2. changed the settings under Options -> C#/VB -> Advanced {Show Compiler Warnings}

Please let me know if this is an expected behavior of 2022

Thanks,
Sandeep

Comment: This may sound stupid, but in the error output window, you can choose the scope of the data to be displayed. This document, entire solution, entire project, etc. Is that set to entire solution? Also, do you have any files that are in your codebase that have not been included into the project file? Those may not show either

Comment: Can you show us a specific example?

Comment: It is working for me now . I had to close the error list and reopen it every time. I think there is a problem with intellisense refresh . It shows after waiting for 30 s. In visual studio 2019 it wasn't a problem.

Comment: Hi ,glad to know you've found the solution to resolve your issue! Please consider answering it and accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting this again -
It is working for me now . I had to close the error list and reopen it every time. I think there is a problem with intellisense refresh . It shows after waiting for 30 s. In visual studio 2019 it wasn't a problem.

Ensure this setting under Tools -> Options -> VisualBasic/C# is set "Entire solution"